# Mininet Python API - CLI Class

Tags: python, mininet

I am having trouble understanding how to use to class properly. Calling the class constructor without a script automatically runs the CLI in interactive mode. Therefore you need to manually exit interactive mode to obtain the class instance. Only then can you call the class methods using said instance.  This seems very strange.

What I am trying to do is write a program which configures the network and then opens several xterm windows on separate nodes and launches an application inside them. Is this possible?

Edit:

For example something like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.log import setLogLevel
from mininet.cli import CLI
from mininet.topolib import TreeTopo

def test():
    "Create and test a simple network"
    net = Mininet(TreeTopo(depth=2,fanout=2))
    net.start()
    cli = CLI(net)
    CLI.do_xterm(cli, "h1 h2")
    net.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setLogLevel('info')
    test()
```

Calling the CLI class constructor in order to obtain the class instance automatically launches mininet in interactive mode. This needs to be manually exited before the call to the do_xterm method can be envoked on the class instance.

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example of your issue? Maybe some code.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose a CLI is made to be used on stdin, so making use of scripting instead of programmatic manipulation of the CLI makes some sense.

If you want to obtain a reference to the cli object without interactive mode, you could make a workaround by creating an empty text file called "null_script" and then calling

```
cli = CLI(net, script='null_script')
```

Your real goal seems to be to programatically open xterms and have them run applications. Since you don't give a reason why you can't use scripts I propose a solution that uses a script. Put the following in a text file:

```
py h1.cmd('screen -dmS mininet.h1')
sh xterm -title Node:h1 -e screen -D -RR -S mininet.h1 &
sh screen -x -S mininet.h1 -X stuff 'ls'`echo '\015'`
```

Using this text file as a script in the cli works for me both using the 'source' command on CLI and by passing the filename into 'sript='.

I took the command arguments from the makeTerm function in [term.py](https://github.com/bigswitch/mininet/blob/acab5349a2a793399e99c40fc878313bf1db887f/mininet/term.py), and the screen stuff arguments from an answer on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/116743/send-command-to-an-already-running-screen-session). Just replace 'ls' with the name of the application you want to run.

Each screen you are trying to attach to needs to have a unique name, otherwise you will get a message listing the matching names and you will have to specify a pid for the correct session, which would complicate things.